# about a question of Math.SE which is migrated to Physics.SE

Tags: discussion

I had asked this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12078/540) earlier in Math.SE but later after not much of a response, i moved it to Physics.SE. Now after waiting for a substantial amount of time there, I wonder if i could migrate/repost it back to Math.SE. I'd like to hear some comments from you about the appropriateness of doing so.

Comment: Apart from *your* need for more answers, could you think of a better reason why that question would be a better fit here than there?

Comment: @J.M. : honestly i do not know where it would be a better fit as I do not know the answer and I would like to atleast hear about it from others. But my hope is that it would reach more audience here.

Comment: @J.M. : Also one strong reason is that the question is about the real world applications of a mathematical concept, and Physics is a subset of the real world applications.

Comment: Honestly, sometimes I hear physicists talk about math and it sounds more of a twisted abuse, less as an application. :-P

Comment: Dear Rajesh, You might want to reevaluate the answer you received regarding OPEs (the one Theo refers to below).  This is one of the deeper topics on the boundary of mathematics and physics.  For a mathematical treatment you can look at the book of Frenkel and Ben-Zvi on Vertex Operator Algebras.  Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I dislike the idea of cross-posting questions on SE. I also believe that one should be able to ask a question wherever it fits best. So had the question started there, I would be perfectly fine seeing it migrated here. But it started here.

I want to make sure I understand the timeline. You wrote it on July 7. No one answered the question. Two days later, it moved to Physics. And since then, it has accumulated 6 answers (with a total of 6 votes between them). I presume that you don't like any of the answers there (though I argue that the Operator Product Expansion is a good example). Four of those answers came within 2 days of the migration.

Taking all this together, it seems to me that it belongs on PhysicsSE and not on MathSE. You could always post a link to your question in the chat (I keep referring people to the chat, because it *could* be useful... maybe...). This meta topic was a good idea, as most of the math power users frequent the meta, and I suspect that a good many have now read your question.

Anyhow, that's how I feel.

Comment: See also [Ryan Budney's answer](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1097) to Rajesh's inquiry on meta.MO whether the question would be appropriate for MO. He summarizes my feelings about this question pretty well. In addition I'm rather annoyed by Rajesh's second comment to Qmechanic's answer. If your formulation is so vague then you shouldn't be astonished that you receive answers that don't capture "the spirit of the question".

Comment: @Theo Well said.

Comment: "If your formulation is so vague then you shouldn't be astonished that you receive answers that don't capture 'the spirit of the question'." - bang on the nose.

Comment: @Theo : I do agree that the formulation of the question is not as clear as that of most of the questions, but i do not think it is beyond repair, more over rpeairing the question, is what i want from the answerers. I wanted to take my comment back on Qmechanic's answer but for some reasons i forgot, and now i left a comment on it. I'd appreciate some comments on the defects in the question. Regards.

Comment: @Rajesh: I seriously appreciate your apology to QMechanic. Since I don't really *know* what you might be looking for it would be good if you could try and elaborate on *why* you consider the examples you received so far as unsatisfactory (be as specific as you can be). One *example* having serious applications (of which you probably know more than me, given your background) that came to my mind would be non-smooth waveforms such as the [sawtooth wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) and its siblings (square wave, pulse wave, triangular wave, etc.)